# Why do textures stick around in the editor?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, uv, uv-image-editor

UV unwrapping a mesh with different object using some image textures has some issues. Specifically, in this case, I have created a table and UV unwrapped the main part(the one that is active below):
[image: table main]

Even when I tab out of edit mode and select a different part of the mesh the texture sticks around in the editor:

[image: image 2]
As you can see, a different object is selected, the UV slot is empty BUT the texture stays. If I UV unwrap it anyway, the texture is automatically applied to the mesh portions as so:
[image: third image]

If I hit the new button:
[image: four]

Blender only has options for generated textures:
[image]

And if I hit the cross button, there is no user for the texture:
[image]
And therefore, I cannot unwrap.

I haven't had much experience with UV unwrapping. What is this problem? Why does this arise? **Is there a way to refresh the UV editor?** How can I fix this?

Comment: You can unwrap when you are in edit mode :/ I'm not sure however what your problem is :/

Comment: @xlxs, I'm not getting the point why the texture sticks around even when we TAB out of edit mode. That would be even after selected a different mesh object, which would confuse during UV wrapping the second object.

Comment: This is good how is it. Of course texture stay in UV/Image editor. You can use one texture for many materials. If you need add more textures, you need attach next one in material node editor and in UV/Image Editor you can switch them. PS: You don't assign texture to object in UV/Image Editor, you must do it in material (node) editor

Comment: The UV editor is merely acting differently than what you expect. As Shubol3D points out, you assign textures in the Materials editor, not the UV editor.

Answer (score 2):

To get rid of unused textures, **you have to save and then reload your file**.

Either use "File - Open Recent - " or hit <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> and then hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>, since your latest save is usually in the first place of the list.

If you want to get rid of a texture despite having it assigned, press <kbd>Shift</kbd> and hit the X button beside the texture's name in the UV/image editor Texture dropdown.

Besides that, textures are kept around on purpose. This comes in handy when you are optimizing your workflow. And you are certainly able to unwrap a model without any texture at all.

Comment: After you remove the textures using the Shift key on the X button, you have to save and reload to really remove it from the file.

Comment: @AnthonyForwood - exactly as I mentioned in my first sentence.

Comment: Yeah, but you should have made it clear that this needs to be done afterwards. You mentioned the Shift key thing last. Kind of confusing for noobs.

Comment: @AnthonyForwood - nope. The Shift Key is optional. As is the information about why Textures are kept in the editor and also the info about the possibility to being able to unwrap objects without textures.

Comment: Without the shift key, you're not unlinking the texture from anything but the current object, so if it's still being used by another one, it won't be completely removed. I have no idea what you mean about "information about why textures are kept in the editor" being optional. You're confused and your information will just confuse others.

Comment: @AnthonyForwood - in this case you are clearly wrong. It's getting ridiculous

Comment: Yes, I agree you are.